# PHP -- Easy Global Access Within Class?

Tags: php

My software loads PHP modules, and supplies to them some nifty globals -- like the current module's filesystem path -- `$module_path`, among others.

```
$module_path = "important/path/to/module"; // predefined by parent script, works at this scope

class Blah {
  function blahBlah(){

    global $module_path;
    require $module_path.'/blah.php'; // ERROR: $module_path not defined??

  }
}

$blah = new Blah();
$blah->blahBlah();
```

Am I not able to access the globals I'm asking for from within my object's method?

I'm fearing that the only logical solution is to completely abandon object-oriented programming in PHP, and revert to a completely flat, top-down, procedural architecture?

Comment: _Configuration files_. Or _dependency injection_. Or just _parameter_. Never `global`

Comment: What's the problem here? With `global $module_path;` you already do have the solution to access your global variable from within your method

Comment: @AlmaDo: What do you mean by "Configuration files" or "dependency injection"? I don't find parameter passing to be even remotely sane for a situation like this, though do find prefixed global variables to be perfectly appropriate for this purpose. These are, after all, seriously variables that are intended to be available totally everywhere (in every module, at least).

Comment: Try using `$GLOBALS['module_path']` instead of `$module_path` inside your class.

Comment: @MerlinDenker: Contrary to your sanity's good assumptions.. No, the example code does indeed *fail.* `global $module_path` is failing to make `$module_path` accessible to the instance method `$blah->blahBlah();` -- I've tested the example code in several combinations, and have so far been unable to acquire the value of `$module_path` in a way which doesn't make me want to rip my hair out and uninstall PHP.

Comment: @ojovirtual: I gave it a shot, but no luck mate.

Comment: @ChaseMoskal I tested it as well, it worked for me. Maybe a matter of configuration? I used myown code, but it does the same... set a global var, declare a class with a method that echoes that global, then create an instance of that class and call the method. Worked.

Comment: @ChaseMoskal maybe the variables you want aren't global variables at all. Are they setted from within another function? If they were global, the should be inside `$GLOBALS`.

Comment: @MerlinDenker: *It is configuration.* I ran [this test code](http://pastebin.com/BcYrX66u) in a standalone test.php file -- it worked fine, outputting the global. I then ran the exact same code, but as a module file. What's freaking me out now, is that it looks like suddenly all of PHP's rules about globals go flying out the window when you're no longer running as the top script. There doesn't seem to be any way for me to get that exact test code snippet to work when it's being run as a module (having been included). Any ideas?

Comment: @ojovirtual: Would there be any reason that [this simple test](http://pastebin.com/BcYrX66u) would fail for an included PHP file, but work fine for top/main script?

Comment: @ChaseMoskal: So you say when you include the test.php (which actually looks exactly like mine, just other names) with php `include()`, then it no longer works? I cannot reproduce that behaviour, it works for me no matter where i declare the global variable, the object or where i call the method...